# Keep placeholder text in UITextField on input in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, placeholder

Is there any way to prevent placeholder text in a UITextField from being overwritten when the text field receives an input? I have a text field that takes an expiration date in this format "MM/YYYY" with placeholder text that reads "MM/YYYY" and I want to remove the placeholder text as it is filled in, not when the first character is entered.

Example:
"1M/YYYY" after first character
"10/YYYY" after the second character
etc.

Comment: Yes; there are a number of ways to accomplish this. What have you tried?

Comment: I can't find any way of doing this, only information on how to change the format/color of placeholder text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the placeholder text, you'll want to set the actual `text` property of the field to MM/YYYY, set the delegate of the text field and listen for this method:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    // update the text of the label
}
```

Inside that method, you can figure out what the user has typed as they type, which will allow you to update the label accordingly.

Comment: This was what I tried doing at first but could not find a way to keep the MM/YYYY text light grey while the user input text stays black. 
edit: I think I may have to use core text to achieve the effect I am looking for.

Comment: @tunam3lt you can accomplish this with attributed strings. Just create an NSAttributedString with the appropriate colors and ranges and set it to the attributedText property of the textField in the above method